# Comparing Dates in Lists between two Dictionaries

Tags: python, date, dictionary, datetime

I have two dictionaries where the values of both the dictionaries are lists of dates. What I would like to do is match the keys from both the dictionaries, and then compare the lists of dates between them in order to determine the total number of days between the dates. However, I only want to do it on the condition the date in the first dictionary is after the date in the second dictionary.

For example, if I have dictionary 1 `dict1` and dictionary 2 `dict` as follows:

```
dict1 = {... , a : ['2022-07-27'] , ...}
dict2 = {... , a : ['2022-07-21'] , ...}
```

Then first, the keys `a` in both `dict1` and `dict2` match, and from the date list I then subtract the date in `dict1` with the date in `dict2` to get 6 days. This example is easy for me to code up, however the problem I have is when the list of dates becomes longer and more complex. For example:

```
dict1 = {... , b : ['2021-09-14', '2022-08-08'], ...}
dict2 = {... , b : ['2022-08-01'], ...}
```

Now, since the first date in `dict1` is before the date in `dict2`, I don't want to subtract it. However, the second date in `dict1` is after the date in `dict2`, so I do want to subtract it to determine the number of days inbetween i.e. `(2022-08-08) - (2022-08-01) = 7 days`

Another example is as follows:

```
dict1 = {... , c : ['2021-07-28', '2022-07-07', '2022-09-17'], ...}
dict2 = {... , c : ['2022-05-01', '2022-07-27'], ...}
```

Same as the previous example, since the first date in `dict1` is before the date in `dict2`, I don't want to subtract it. However, since the second date in `dict1` is after the first date in `dict2`, I do want to subtract it to determine the number of days inbetween i.e. `(2022-07-07) - (2022-05-01) = x number of days`. And, since the third date in `dict1` is after the second date in `dict2`, I also want to subtract it to determine the number of days inbetween i.e. `(2022-09-17) - (2022-07-27) = y number of days` and since I now have two values `x` and `y`, I want to add them together to get the total i.e. `x + y = total number of days`

Is there a computationally light way of doing this? Thank you!

Comment: you could use the datetime module to get the difference between two dates

Comment: I've looked into it before, and if both the lists were equal/more predictable then I could very easily do it. However, since the conditions I have complicate things, I'm not too sure what the best approach is - I can think of using `for` loops, but I feel like it might be computationally intensive since I have two iterate over many, many lists :(

Comment: Do the dates in dict2 only match up with a single value in dict1? (to get the days in between for those two dates)?

Comment: @AndrewRyan, Yes, for each date in dict2 should only match up to a single value in dict1, as long as the date in dict2 occurs after the date in dict1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way that you can do what you want:

**this answer is assuming that all of the dates are in chronological order**

```
import datetime

def convert_to_time_obj(str_date):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    
# get common keys between both dicts
dict1_keys = set(dict1.keys())
dict2_keys = set(dict2.keys())
common_keys = dict1_keys.intersection(dict2_keys)

# compare dict elements
for key in common_keys: # go through all common keys
    total_days = 0 # used as a sum for case #3
    multiple_dates_used = False # triggers the printing of total_days
    last_index = 0 # assuming that all of the dates are in order from earliest to latest. to save time don't go through previously looked at values
    for start_value in dict2[key]:
        start_date = convert_to_time_obj(start_value)
        
        for index, compare_value in enumerate(dict1[key][last_index:]): # grab the index to selectively not go through those element again based on the dates in dict2 having to be larger
            compare_date = convert_to_time_obj(compare_value)
            if compare_date <= start_date:
                continue # skip over these dates
            days_between = compare_date - start_date
            print(days_between) # prints the days between only 2 dates
            
            multiple_dates_used = bool(total_days) # updates to True when total_days > 0, therefore this would be a total of 2 or more dates with in between days
            total_days += days_between.days
            last_index = index + 1
            break # as only using the first set of dates for in between days
    if multiple_dates_used:
        print(total_days) # prints all of the days as in case 3
```

Let me know if this helps and anything I may have missed with what you were describing.

Comment: Sidenote: You could just do `common_keys = dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()` to get the common keys (result is a set).

Comment: Shouldn't you pull the `last_index = 0` before the loop `for index, compare_value in enumerate(dict1[key][last_index:]):` and modify `last_index = index` to `last_index += index + 1`? Otherwise `enumerate(dict1[key][last_index:])` would always be `enumerate(dict1[key][0:])`.

Comment: @Timus thanks. was writing this late last night.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, this answer solved my question, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative (not so different from Andrew's solution, though), which is using stacks instead of index book-keeping. I find that better readable. (The assumption here too is that the date-lists are in ascending order).

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

dict1 = ...
dict2 = ...

res = {}
for key in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys():
    res[key] = 0
    dates1, dates2 = [*reversed(dict1[key])], [*reversed(dict2[key])]
    while dates2 and dates1:
        date2 = dt.strptime(dates2.pop(), "%Y-%m-%d")
        while dates1:
            if (date1 := dt.strptime(dates1.pop(), "%Y-%m-%d")) > date2:
                res[key] += (date1 - date2).days
                break
print(res)
```

The first step is reversing the lists for a common key. Afterwards the processing can simply be done by popping items from the stacks. I did some testing and found a slight performance advantage (like 10% faster).

Comment: though negligible now, would converting excess items (non-matched later dates) to datetime objects cause a difference (depending on how many matching keys there are with excess dates)?

Comment: @AndrewRyan Excellent point, thanks! I ran some tests and conversion on demand is definitely faster. Will update.